# Handle Disconnect Express JS Throw Error Access Denied for user localhost

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

hello i'm trying to handle disconnect my server express js , i'm using this code of handle disconnect , and it throws error access denied for user in localhost.

```
var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
                                                  // the old one cannot be reused.

  connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                          // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
      handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
      throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnect();
```

and my connection host

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');  
 var db_config = module.exports = {

     'connection': {
         'host': 'localhost',
         'user': 'root',
         'password': ''
     },
  'database': 'database'
 };
```

and it happends on my server also which is throwing error like access denied for user localhost.

the error shows like this

```
Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'databases'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling the empty user (at) localhost is not allowed.
That leads me to the db_config:
Replace `db_config` with `db_config.connection` in the code line

```
connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config.connection);
```